# How to import excel sheets with the same pattern in R?

Tags: r

Suppose that we have 3 excel sheets are sheet1_test, sheet2_test, and sheet3_test. The common pattern of these sheets can be test or _test. So, how can we import them in such a situation? I don't know if it will work but if there were multiple files I would use the following code.

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls|*.xlsx")
df_list <- lapply(file_list, read_excel)
masterdf <- ldply(df_list, data.frame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `excel_sheets` to get the name of sheets and keep only those sheets that have `"test"` in it and import it with `lapply` or `map_df`.

```
library(readxl)

file_name <- '/path/to/file/filename.xlsx'
sheets <- excel_sheets(file_name)
correct_sheets <- grep('_test', sheets, value = TRUE)
data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(correct_sheets, read_excel, path = file_name))
#Can also use `purrr::map_df`
#data <- purrr::map_df(correct_sheets, read_excel, path = file_name)
```